# Unity: Fit size of parent to size of childs

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent-child, scale

I have an empty in a Canvas that has multiple objects as children. More children are added to the parent as the game progresses. I want the parent to fit the size to its children.

I already read a lot about this topic, but every time I came across the ContentSizeFitter, which unfortunately does not work for me, because it needs a layout group, which I do not have, because the children do not have an order and are wildly placed.

I am using Unity 2018.3.4f1 Personal.

**Not sized parent:**

[image: Example]

**Sized parent (Red: New, Green: Old):**

[image: Example 2]

**Structure:**

```
Canvas
 |- Empty
     |- Child 1
     |- Child 2
     |- Child X
```

Comment: 4 vertexes will define the parent's size: the leftmost, rightmost, topmost and bottommost ones. Having them, you can measure the center and the size of the parent. Calculate these vertexes in your Update method and you are good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a small piece of code that does its job, or does it the way I want and it is enough for me:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SizeFitter : MonoBehaviour {
    public void CheckForChanges() {
        RectTransform children = transform.GetComponentInChildren<RectTransform>();

        float min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y;
        min_x = max_x = transform.localPosition.x;
        min_y = max_y = transform.localPosition.y;

        foreach (RectTransform child in children) {
            Vector2 scale = child.sizeDelta;
            float temp_min_x, temp_max_x, temp_min_y, temp_max_y;

            temp_min_x = child.localPosition.x - (scale.x / 2);
            temp_max_x = child.localPosition.x + (scale.x / 2);
            temp_min_y = child.localPosition.y - (scale.y / 2);
            temp_max_y = child.localPosition.y + (scale.y / 2);

            if (temp_min_x < min_x)
                min_x = temp_min_x;
            if (temp_max_x > max_x)
                max_x = temp_max_x;

            if (temp_min_y < min_y)
                min_y = temp_min_y;
            if (temp_max_y > max_y)
                max_y = temp_max_y;
        }

        GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you indeed used my idea but with a better approach, COOL!! but I encourage you to avoid using that in Update, that will be incredibly heavy in processor. You can avoid it making a function that makes the parent move or scale or anything the children so it only rescales when values change.

Comment: So weirdly, this doesn't quite work for me; the parent rectangle is the correct size, but it's way off center -- it seems to grow upward while half the content leaks below it.  Changing the pivot to 1,1 or 0,1 doesn't work, nor do messing with the anchors.  Anyone figure this out? Do the rectTransforms need to be a certain layout style?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the leftiest border and the rightiest border and then add the difference of that value as `sizeDelta` of the parent `RectTransform`.

That should fix the size (repeat with top and bottom for Y).

For the position you can get the Top Left corner with leftiest border and top border in a `Vector2`, then you set that vector as `anchoredPosition` to the parent `RectTransform`.

Note that the pivot of the parent must be on Top Left corner for this to work.

This code only approached something, but it is not good enough.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FitParentToChildren : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region INTERNAL

    public RectTransform parent;
    public RectTransform[] children;

    public float minX = 100000;
    public float maxX = -100000;
    public float minY = 100000;
    public float maxY = -100000;

    #endregion

    #region INITIALIZATION

    void Awake()
    {
        parent = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        children = GetComponentsInChildren<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        SetMinMaxValues();
        FitToChildren();
    }

    #endregion

    #region BEHAVIOURS

    private void FitToChildren()
    {
        parent.sizeDelta = GetNewRect();
        parent.anchoredPosition = GetTopLeftCornerPositon();
    }

    private void SetMinMaxValues()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < children.Length; i++)
        {
            float tempMinX = children[i].anchoredPosition.x - children[i].sizeDelta.x / 2;
            if (tempMinX < minX) minX = tempMinX;

            float tempMaxX = children[i].anchoredPosition.x + children[i].sizeDelta.x / 2;
            if (tempMaxX > maxX) maxX = tempMaxX;

            float tempMinY = children[i].anchoredPosition.y - children[i].sizeDelta.y / 2;
            if (tempMinY < minY) minY = tempMinY;

            float tempMaxY = children[i].anchoredPosition.y + children[i].sizeDelta.y / 2;
            if (tempMaxY > maxY) maxY = tempMaxY;
        }
    }

    private Vector2 GetNewRect()
    {
        return new Vector2 (maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
    }

    private Vector2 GetTopLeftCornerPositon()
    {
        return new Vector2 (minX, maxY);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**GIF HERE**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your code didn't work out all right, but it definitely helped me and gave me some good ideas.

Comment: I had little time to help, but its something XD

Answer (score 1):

```
Bounds bound = new Bounds();
for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; ++i)
{
    RectTransform child = children[i];
    if (child != null && child.gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        Vector2 pos = child.localPosition;
        Vector2 min = pos - child.sizeDelta * child.pivot;
        Vector2 max = min + child.sizeDelta;
        Bounds temp = new Bounds();
        temp.SetMinMax(min, max);
        bound.Encapsulate(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  It loops through all the children of the object of your choice, then finds the renderer bounds of those objects and updates the min and max as it goes.  At the end of the Start() function, the variables min and max hold the coordinates to the corners of the box that defines the bounds.

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        Vector2 min = new Vector2 (0, 0);
        Vector2 max = new Vector2 (0, 0);

        GetParentBounds (gameObject, out min, out max);
        Debug.Log (min);
        Debug.Log (max);

    }

    void GetParentBounds (GameObject GO, out Vector2 pMin, out Vector2 pMax)
    {
        Transform[] ts = GO.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform> ();

        Vector2 parentMin = new Vector2 (float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
        Vector2 parentMax = new Vector2 (float.MinValue, float.MinValue);

        foreach (Transform t in ts) {
            Renderer rend = t.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
            if (rend != null) {
                Vector2 min = rend.bounds.min;
                Vector2 max = rend.bounds.max;
                Debug.Log (string.Format ("[{0}, {1}], [{2}, {3}]", min.x, min.y, max.x, max.y));
                parentMin.x = Mathf.Min (parentMin.x, min.x);
                parentMin.y = Mathf.Min (parentMin.y, min.y);
                parentMax.x = Mathf.Max (parentMax.x, max.x);
                parentMax.y = Mathf.Max (parentMax.y, max.y);
            }
        }

        pMin = parentMin;
        pMax = parentMax;
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have to use that data you got somehow

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. The parent is a child of a Canvas, so it has a Canvas Renderer. And `t.GetComponent<Renderer> ()` returns null.

Comment: Do they have meshfilters?  you could try changing the inside of the foreach to this:  
           Renderer mf = t.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
            if (mf!= null) {
                Vector2 min = mf.mesh.bounds.min;
                Vector2 max = mf.mesh.bounds.max;
                parentMin.x = Mathf.Min (parentMin.x, min.x);
                parentMin.y = Mathf.Min (parentMin.y, min.y);
                parentMax.x = Mathf.Max (parentMax.x, max.x);
                parentMax.y = Mathf.Max (parentMax.y, max.y);
            }

Comment: No, they only have a RectTransform, CanvasRenderer, Image, Outline and a collider.

Answer (score 0):

It took me four hours to figure it out. Thanks JaegonDo for an idea how to calculate Transforms min/max, however Bounds() gave me error in few cases. Once we know the size, we have to calculate the bottom-leftmost position and move every child relative to it. However, I will probably stick with HorizontalLayoutGroup + ContentSizeFitter solution.

[image]

```
RectTransform parent = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
RectTransform children = transform.GetComponentInChildren<RectTransform>();

// Calculate the parent's boundary and bottom-leftmost child(s)
Vector2 pMin = Vector2.positiveInfinity;
Vector2 pMax = Vector2.negativeInfinity;
Vector2 absMin = Vector2.positiveInfinity;
foreach (RectTransform child in children) {
  if (child != null && child.gameObject.activeSelf) {
    Vector2 min = (Vector2)child.localPosition - child.sizeDelta * child.pivot;
    Vector2 max = min + child.sizeDelta;
    pMin.x = Mathf.Min(pMin.x, min.x);
    pMin.y = Mathf.Min(pMin.y, min.y);
    pMax.x = Mathf.Max(pMax.x, max.x);
    pMax.y = Mathf.Max(pMax.y, max.y);

    absMin.x = Mathf.Min(absMin.x, min.x);
    absMin.y = Mathf.Min(absMin.y, min.y);
  }
}
parent.sizeDelta = new Vector2(pMax.x - pMin.x, pMax.y - pMin.y);

// Adjust the positions of its children relative to its bottom-left corner
foreach (RectTransform child in children) {
  if (child != null && child.gameObject.activeSelf) {
    Vector2 min = (Vector2)child.localPosition - child.sizeDelta * child.pivot;
    Vector2 offset = min - absMin;
    child.SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Left, offset.x, child.rect.size.x);
    child.SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Bottom, offset.y, child.rect.size.y);
  }
}
```

Just come up with even nicer solution for size calculation with rect.min/rect.max:

```
Vector2 min = Vector2.positiveInfinity;
Vector2 max = Vector2.negativeInfinity;
foreach (RectTransform child in children) {
  if (child != null && child.gameObject.activeSelf) {
    Vector2 minLocal = (Vector2)child.localPosition + rectTransform.rect.min;
    Vector2 maxLocal = (Vector2)child.localPosition + rectTransform.rect.max;
    for (int axis = 0; axis <= 1; axis++) {
      min[axis] = Mathf.Min(min[axis], minLocal[axis]);
      max[axis] = Mathf.Max(max[axis], maxLocal[axis]);
    }
  }
}
this.rectTransform.sizeDelta = max - min;
```